# How do I migrate data from a local Cassandra cluster to a Docker instance?

Tags: docker, cassandra, database-migration

I have one Cassandra database node locally. It is part of other system. This is not simple data but complex large amounts of information that I would like to transfer taking into account the entire keyspace.

I would like to switch to docker. I have a problem with migrating existing data.
I am doing a keyspace snapshot which is responsible for the files stored:

```
nodetool cleanup <keyspace>
nodetool snapshot <keyspace> -t <backup_name>
```

There is no problem with creating a snapshot and restoring it on the same instance:

```
service cassandra stop
for I in `ls /var/lib/cassandra/data/<keyspace>`  ; do rm -f /var/lib/cassandra/data/<keyspace>/$I/* ; done
(...)
# Moving files to /var/lib/cassandra/data/<keyspace>
(...)
service cassandra restart
```

The data is not protected, so I thought I'd just move the snapshot data to where the Cassandra docker image volumes was stored. This attempt failed. I tried to analyze the logs coming from the Cassandra docker image but found nothing there that could point me to the problem. I noticed that when turning on the docker with Cassandra it doesn't show an error it just creates new files in keyspace with a different UUID.

1. Is there any official procedure for migrating data to docker instance?
2. Does Cassandra's version matter? The tests I did were with the 3.11.11 to 3.11.11 docker and the 3.11.11 to 4.0.0 docker. Same final results.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really have anything to do with Cassandra being in Dockerised. The real problem is the method by which you tried to clone the data.

For a bit of background, the directory names for the CQL tables have a UUID suffix to make them unique in case a table has been dropped and recreated with the same name ([CASSANDRA-5202](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5202)). Since the directory names are unique to each cluster, you cannot just do a straight copy of the whole keyspace from one cluster to another. You will need to copy the data one table at a time.

You can use the same steps I previously documented in https://community.datastax.com/questions/4534/ which uses the "refresh method". Here are the high-level steps:

**STEP 1** - For the first table, create the schema on the destination cluster.

**STEP 2** - Copy the table snapshot from the source to the corresponding table's subdirectory on the destination node.

**STEP 3** - On the destination node, force Cassandra to reload the new SSTables on disk with:

```
$ nodetool refresh -- ks_name table_name
```

**STEP 4** - Check the Cassandra `system.log` to verify that the SSTables were loaded.

**STEP 5** - Repeat steps 1 to 4 above until all tables have been migrated.

Check the link I posted above for further details. Cheers!